# Request different characters per font with Google Fonts?

Tags: html, fonts, google-font-api

Google Fonts supports [loading specific characters of a font](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Optimizing_Requests):

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata&text=Hello
```

Google Fonts also supports [loading multiple families and styles with one request](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Syntax):

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine:bold,bolditalic|Inconsolata:italic|Droid+Sans
```

Is there a way to load different character sets for different families without making multiple requests? It seems that since `text` is a separate query parameter the answer is "no, the `text` param applies to all requested families and styles`, but figured I'd throw it out there...

**UPDATE:** @Gothburz' answer shows it's possible to load specific `subset`s of multiple fonts with one request, but I haven't found a way to load specific `text` ranges with one request.

Answer (score 2):

You can add character subsets in the URL using extra parameter `&subset` with comma separated value, like this:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700|Ubuntu:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Example of multipls subsets & fonts:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,300&subset=latin,cyrillic|PT+Sans:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: That will load the `latin` and `latin-ext` subsets for both Ubuntu and Open Sans, though, will it not?

Comment: It looks like this works fine with formal subsets (e.g. `latin`, `latin-ext`, `cyrillc`), but it appears that specifying a particular character range does not work with this same syntax for multiple fonts (using `text=` instead of `subset=`). When specifying `text=`, only the first requested font displays correctly. Editing my question to make it more explicit that I'm asking about `text=`.